# Laravel Redirect::to not changing url

Tags: url, redirect, laravel-4

I am trying to redirect admin to some other URL by using Redirect::To method. But it is not working.

```
public function __construct()
{
    if(Session::has('event')  && Request::segment(1) == 'admin')
    {
        $event_name = Session::get('event');
        return Redirect::To($event_name.'/admin');
    }
}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::resource('{event}/admin', 'AdminController');
```

I have defined route for such url pattern in the routes.php. I am just checking if session is set for **event** key then change the url to /XXX/admin, where XXX is the name of the event.

Problem is that URL is not being changed...and same page url is refreshed

Am i missing something?

Comment: You are missing one thing for sure - what's the problem.

Comment: Problem is that URL is not being changed...and same page url is refreshed

Comment: Yes, the route will work, however mind that `event` will be a route prefix, so it will be passed to your controller methods as 1st parameter. The problem is that `__construct` doesn't return anything. So you won't get any redirect with this code, period. Simply define it somewhere else.